# create sub-list of order integers present in a list and store them in another nested list in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array list like this:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,9,1,12,9,8,7,8,9,10,12,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to create a sub-list from a list of ordered numbers (which are already in sequence in arr_list for e.g. 1,2,3,4 are already in order, similarly 7,8,9,10 and last 10 numbers)

Final output will look like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

Tried comparing if the i'th element of first for loop is less than the j'th element of second for loop.

This is what i've tried:

```py
sub_list=[]
for i in range(0,length_of_list):
    for j in range(i+1,length_of_list):
        if (arr_list[i] < arr_list[j]):
            sub_list.append(arr_list[i]) 
        else:
            pass
```

New to python, any leads are much appreciated.

Comment: what u have tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16693888/ghost-ops   so far i did this, but this is for only the sequence values i can get like 1,2,3,4 but it's not working either and failing where 1 is smaller than 12 while compairing i < j                                                                                                                   
'code' sub_list=[]
for i in range(0,length_of_list):
    for j in range(i+1,length_of_list):
        if (arr_list[i] < arr_list[j]):
            sub_list.append(arr_list[i])
        else:
            pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```py
res, temp = [], []
lst = [1,2,3,4,9,1,12,9,8,7,8,9,10,12,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in lst:
    if (not temp) or (temp[-1] == i-1):
        temp.append(i)
    else:
        res.append(temp)
        temp = [i]
res.append(temp)
print([i for i in res if len(i)>1])
```

Outputs:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

tell me if its okay for you...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16693888/ghost-ops it's working ... i was just trying the -1 approach however still wasn't getting the list of numbers... Anyways Thanks.